# Minimum value between 2 items of a sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, complexity-theory

I am trying to make a program that will save a sequence of numbers in an array in O(N) time in order to answer quickly (O(logn)) to the following.

min(int i,int j): Returns the minimum value's possition in the sequence between possitions i and j.

e.g if the sequence is  A = (22, 51, 83, 42, 90, 102, 114, 35) and i call min(3,6)
it will return 4 because 42< 83,90,102.

I understand that it is not possible to achieve quick time if the values of the sequence are not sorted and because i want to achive O(logn) i thought of implementing a binary tree.

The problem is that i cannot figure out in which way i should place the values of the sequence in the binary tree to access them quickly for min() to work as i need.

Comment: This is a typical problem to solve with an interval tree. You can construct it in O(n) time and then run queries in O(log n).

Comment: Unrelated, but you're deviating from Java norms if you say that range 3-6 covers `83, 42, 90, 102`, for two reasons: 1) Java arrays are 0-based, but if index 3 is value `83`, then you're using 1-based logic. 2) Java ranges are lower-inclusive, upper-exclusive, but if range 3-6 covers 4 values, then you're using upper-inclusive logic.

Comment: why place them anywhere if you already have them sorted? just use the existing array as is and use their index for O(1) lookup...

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz The index may have some other significant meaning

Comment: @Ardavel, turn your comment to an answer.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, thanks for your suggestion. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical problem to be solved with an interval tree. You can construct it in `O(n)` time and then run queries in `O(log n)`.

A general idea is to have a perfect binary tree stored in an array where a node at index `i` has its children at indices `2i` and `2i+1`. In the leaves you store the values of your sequence and for every non-leaf node you store the minimum of all its descendants. If you construct the tree from the leaves upwards, you can do it in `O(n)` time.

To run a query for an interval `[a; b]`, you can take two basic approaches (both work in `O(log n)` time):

- going towards the root from the leaves `a` and `b`
- recursively going downwards the tree starting from the root

A description of both methods you can easily find on the Internet under 'interval tree' phrase. For your problem I definitely recommend the former one because it should be a bit faster.

As requested, I've extended my answer with the instructions for querying a tree. Let's have a closer look at the bottom-up approach which I've suggested for your problem. I'm going to assume that the array is indexed from `0` to `n - 1`. I also assume that `n` is equal to `2^k` for some natural `k`. If not, you increase it to the nearest power of 2 by adding `+Inf` elements at the end of the bottom level in case of querying for the minimum. It won't affect any valid query and you get a perfect binary tree which can be easily indexed as I described previously. For a comfortable implementation I suggest using index 1 for the root and this is also assumed for this description.

This drawing should make things more clear. The black indices at the bottom are the indices from the original array. The green indices next to each node are the indices in the tree. For now ignore the rectangles as they pertain to a query example.

[image: Interval tree example]

By `query(a, b)` we are going to denote a query for the minimum in the interval `[a; b]` (inclusive). Firstly, a special case: when `a` is equal to `b`, we just return `tree[n + a]` (please note that this is the correct index when `tree[1]` is the root).

Let's move to a more complicated case when `a != b`. The clue of the algorithm is that we can split any interval into `O(log n)` base intervals which have no common elements and fully cover the original interval. The size of each base interval is a power of 2 and each base interval is represented by one of our nodes. When we list all relevant intervals we just need to take the minimum of their nodes to get the answer for `query(a, b)`.

Now we are going to describe the method of choosing base intervals. They are all surrounded by rectangles in the example image. Have a look at the following code snippet:

```
int x = a + n;
int y = b + n;
int result = Math.min(tree[x], tree[y]);

while (x / 2 != y / 2) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      result = Math.min(result, tree[x + 1]);
    }
    if (y % 2 == 1) {
      result = Math.min(result, tree[y - 1]);
    }

    x /= 2;
    y /= 2;
}
```

At first we convert the original indices into the indices in the tree. Then we take into account the single-item intervals containing the boundaries of your query. Remember that I've excluded the special case when `a == b`.

The algorithm proceeds as follows, moving upwards the tree. Whenever `x % 2 == 0` we take into account the interval which is the sibling of `x` in the tree. Please check that this sibling is always totally contained in the interval `[a; b]`. The same we do for `y % 2 == 1` with the exception that the sibling is on the left of `y`. When `x / 2 == y / 2` it means that `x` and `y` are now siblings and we should stop the algorithm. You can check by yourself that this approach chooses the intervals in the way they fully cover `[a; b]`.

Please note that we can check at most 4 nodes in the bottom level of the tree. On each other level we are going to check no more than 2 nodes. As there are `O(log n)` levels of the tree we can see that the time complexity of any query is `O(log n)`.

Bonus - modifying the array. The problem you've described doesn't require modifying the array but in a basic case it's so clean that I'm going to add it here. If you also would like to handle `set(a, v)` instruction which means `array[a] = v` you can easily do it in `O(log n)` time. Firstly you set `tree[a + n] = v` and than you go towards the root updating the minimums on your path.

Comment: If i get this right the tree generated from the sequence i gave as an example sould be like this : https://postimg.org/image/ei2pczqsv/ 

Can you expain how the algorithm will work if i say for example min(4,6)?

Comment: I'm on my way extending the answer.

Comment: @Bill I've described the algorithm in details. Please accept the answer if it meets your needs.